# Creating a 'Notch' in CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on an HTML 5 app. This app will have one solid blue horizontal nav bar. The sub nav items will appear in another horizontal light-blue nav bar below it. When a user clicks an item in either the nav bar or the sub nav bar, I want a notch to appear with the selected item such that it would looks something like this:

```
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
| Item 1     Item 2     Item 3    |
|   ^                             |
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
| Child 1     Child 2     Child 3 |
|               ^                 |
+----------------------------------
|                                 |
|  Content goes here              |
+---------------------------------+
```

Currently, my HTML looks like the following:

```
<div class="row mainNav pad-1">
  <nav>
    Item 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Item 2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Item 3
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="row subNav pad-1">
  <nav>
    Child 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="sub-nav-arrow-up">Child 2</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Child 3
  </nav>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like the following:

```
.mainNav
{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    line-height: 2.4rem;
    padding: 0rem 1.0rem;
}

.subNav
{
    background-color: #40566B;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 2.4rem;
    padding: 0rem 1.0rem;
}

div.sub-nav-arrow-up
{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid #fff;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My problem is, my notch doesn't line up correctly. I need it to align against the bottom of the parent nav's horizontal bar. I also need the notch to be centered in regards to the selected nav item. I can't figure out how to do these two things in CSS. I believe my wrapper span is the incorrect approach as it causes the size of the nav bar to increase. In addition, the notice is not centered properly. I'm not sure what to do.

Is there a way to do this with pure CSS? Or do I have to whip up a JavaScript solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Any chance you can set up what you have so far in a fiddle?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle, that seems to approximate what you are looking for... wouldn't recommend menus with non-blanking-spaces as their spacers... but this may answer your question.  http://jsfiddle.net/7YsLQ/  I removed a couple items from .sub-nav-arrow-up and changed it from div to span.sub-nav-arrow-up.

Comment: If you're going to call them child elements, they should be children of the parent. As you have it set up, they are sibling elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using appropriate tags with css instead of using  . Using jeremyasnyder's jsfiddle code I have knocked up an example using ul and li tags. This would still need javascript to make function but does not rely on

http://jsfiddle.net/MN3eM/3/

HTML

```
<p>Child 3 selected:</p>
<div class="row mainNav pad-1">
  <nav>
      <ul><li class="selected">Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="row subNav pad-1">
  <nav>
      <ul><li>Child 1</li><li class="selected">Child 2</li><li>Child 3</li></ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mainNav { background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); line-height:2.4rem; padding:0rem 1.0rem; }
.subNav { background-color:#40566B; color:#000; line-height:2.4rem; padding:0rem 1.0rem; }
.mainNav nav ul li.selected {
    border-left: 6px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 6px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 10px solid #40566B; 
    text-align:center;
}
.subNav nav ul li.selected {
    border-left: 6px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 6px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff; 
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul { padding:0;margin:0;list-style:none; }
nav ul:after { content:"";display:table;clear:both; }
nav ul li { float: left; margin: 0 10px;}
```

Additional: I don't know what your project is, but you might want to look into responsive menus which will work on all devices http://responsivenavigation.net/